# Timestamp in log4net, is it the time when the log entry is generated or when it is written to file?

Tags: c#, log4net

We are testing the whole time delay between several software components which are communicating with each other through several IPC methods. Since some components are not written by us, the only tools we have are the log files generated by `log4net` (those components are wirtten in `C#`). We have configured the rolling file logger whose configuraitons look like this:

```
<appender name="RollingPerfAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="D:\Logs\my_log.log"/>
  <appendToFile value="true"/>
  <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1"/>
  <maximumFileSize value="20MB"/>
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffffff}, %-5level, server, %-25.25logger, &quot;%message&quot;%newline"/>
  </layout>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
    <levelMin value="FATAL" />
    <levelMax value="FATAL" />
  </filter>
</appender>
```

So now the log items look like this:

```
2021-06-10 10:39:52.987672, ERROR, server, "MY CUSTOM LOG GENERATED ON 2021-06-10 10:39:52.885126"
```

Now my question is, what is the tiemstamp (2021-06-10 10:39:52.987672) of it? Is it when the log entry is generated in the code, or when it is written to the file? I am asking because in this custom log I actually put the execution time in the log message (2021-06-10 10:39:52.885126), and we can see the time difference is as big as 100ms (I tried to set `ImmediateFlush` to `True` and changed it to `False`, it doesn't make much difference). But 100ms is too big for us to analyze the performance , because there are many other log items whose log messages are not controlled by us so we can only use the timestamp in the log itself. But if they are not exactly (or very close to) when those logs are generated in the code, the whole analysis will not be accurate enough (the whole delay is 200ms something, so 100ms inaccuracy in the log is way too big).

So how can I make the timestamp on the log items (close to) the time when it is generated in the code?

Comment: It should be the time the log is generated.  But don't forget, there is a delay between when you create and set your DateTime object until the Log Entry is created and it's DateTime obect is set.  If you are using Async methods then this time could be more significant.

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith Thank you for your reply. Could you maybe explain a bit more on using `Async methods`? Or how can I check what is this 100ms delay? This custom log message was created by me but using the dll/API provided by the component (which writes lots of other logs without timestamp in the log message) that I was referring to.